# Source on smooth equivalence relations under continuous reducibility?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

*This question was [asked and bountied](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393808/degrees-of-smooth-equivalence-relations) at MSE, but received no answer.*

In the context of Borel reducibility, smooth equivalence relations (see the introduction of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1990-03-04/S0894-0347-1990-1057041-5/S0894-0347-1990-1057041-5.pdf)) are rather boring since everything boils down to the number of classes. However, the situation seems more interesting when we restrict attention to *continuous* reducibility. I'd like to know more about the structure of smooth equivalence relations with respect to continuous reducibility; what is a good source on this topic? *(I'm happy to restrict to equivalence relations on Baire space if that would help, but in general I'm interested in arbitrary Polish spaces.)*

Comment: Let me ask a more basic question. Every $G_{\delta}$ equivalence relation on a Polish space is smooth. What is an example of a smooth Borel equivalence relation which is not potentially-$G_{\delta}$? (Potentially-$\Gamma$ means that it is in the pointclass $\Gamma$ for some finer Polish topology inducing the same Borel structure.)

Comment: @Burak I like that question very much!

Comment: The following paper might be of some interest. [On the complexity of Borel equivalence relations with some countability property](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/0000-000-00/S0002-9947-2019-07942-4/S0002-9947-2019-07942-4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this structure must be pretty complicated. For example, consider Brownian motion $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ with the equivalence relations
$$t\sim_\omega s\iff W_t(\omega)=W_s(\omega).$$
Here $\omega\in\Omega$ is an outcome from the sample space, giving a particular path of Brownian motion.

This $\sim_\omega$ is smooth. It seems that these equivalence relations should almost surely not be continuously reducible to eachother, i.e., for almost all $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\Omega\times\Omega$ there should not be any continuous $f$ with
$$t\sim_{\omega_1} s\iff f(t)\sim_{\omega_2}f(s).$$
However I don't have a proof of that... just a thought!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Brownian motion - can you say a bit about what $W_t(\omega)$ (etc.) is (or point me to a text in case that's too much material to quickly summarize)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It's a non-differentiable-but-Hölder-continuous-function-valued random variable...

Comment: @NoahSchweber anyway here's some more about this idea https://mathoverflow.net/q/345528/4600

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, since it is not a perfect fit. But I just thought I would mention the following paper, which is concerned not with continuous reducibility, but computable reducibility.

- *Coskey, Amuel; Hamkins, Joel David; Miller, Russell*, [**The hierarchy of equivalence relations on the natural numbers under computable reducibility**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/equivalence-relations-on-naturals/), [DOI:10.3233/COM-2012-004](http://dx.doi.org/10.3233/COM-2012-004), Computability 1, No. 1, 15-38 (2012). [ZBL1325.03049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1325.03049).

This is not the same thing, of course, but since computable functions on a countable space can be seen as continuous on the reals, it might be a source of some examples.

Comment: If we restrict to computable, my "answer" becomes a lot easier to prove too (and the event becomes clearly measurable)